# Solve for $k$ in the equation ${\sqrt{k + \sqrt{x-k}}} -x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, nested-radicals

> Solve for $k$ in the equation ${\sqrt{k + \sqrt{x-k}}} -x = 0$

I could only try standard methods so far.

${\sqrt{k - \sqrt{x+k}}} = x$

$({\sqrt{k - \sqrt{x+k}}})^2 = x^2$

${{k - \sqrt{x+k}}} = x^2$

${{k - \sqrt{x+k}}} = x^2$

${\sqrt{x+k}} = k - x^2$

$ x + k = k^2 - 2kx^2 + x^4$

$ k^2 - 2kx^2 + x^4-x-k = 0$

That's as far as I got. Any suggestions on how to isolate $k$ here?

Comment: Try to use the quadratic formula: $Ak^2 + Bk + C = 0 \implies k = \frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$.

Comment: Crap, I totally forgot about this! thanks!

Comment: btw don't forget to check that the expressions for the solution(s) you find are valid and also for which $x$ they are valid. Note that we need: $x - k \geq 0$ for $\sqrt{x-k}$ to be defined and also the $\cdots$ in $\sqrt{\cdots}$ in the final expression for $k$ will have to be positive. This should place some constraints on $x$.

Comment: Which means one out of the two possible solutions for k should (generally) be eliminated?

Comment: I'm not saying that will be the case here (though that could happen as squaring square-roots can something lead to false solutions). It's a good habit to check that the steps make sense. I was more hinting towards finding the range of $x$ for which the formula you find is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separate this into

$$k^2-k(2x^2-1)+(x^4-x) = 0$$

and use the quadratic formula to get

$$k = \frac{2x^2-1\pm\sqrt{-4x^2+4x+1}}{2}$$

One can check to see which of these possible solutions work, although that is fairly cumbersome.

Comment: I am such an idiot, thanks for clarifying this